# Terraform Apply updates to AWS Cognito User Pool Domain causes AWS 409 error: CNAMEAlreadyExists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

I've deployed cognito resources including a custom user pool domain resource using Terraform to AWS. I've made some changes to the configuration of the user pool and when I run `terraform apply`, the plan shows that the custom domain will need to be updated as well; To be honest, I'm not sure why since I did not make changes to the domain name.

When I attempt to apply the changes, it gives me the following error message:

> Error: Error creating Cognito User Pool Domain:
> InvalidParameterException: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are
> already associated with a different resource. (Service:
> AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists;
> Request ID: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx; Proxy: null)

To me this appears to be due to Terraform attempting to register the exact same CNAME as the user pool custom domain.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is it doing that when clearly I didn't change the custom domain in Terraform configurations?
2. How can I rectify this issue without having to destroy all of my cognito resources and deploying them from scratch?

Comment: Do you have example of the TF code that you update and gives the error?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the code base actually. All I did was add new values for the app client's callback and logout urls.

Comment: The error is from CloudFront (CF) `AmazonCloudFront`. Is cognito using CF somehow?

Comment: Yes the custom domain feature requires a route53 A record for the domain to be created with its value set to a cloudfront distribution. The distribution is created automatically by AWS to host the cognito login portal.

Comment: What aws privider version do you use? There used to be [bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5313) with cognito domains which could explain your issue.

Comment: I'm using aws provider version 3.30.0